# change path to log file from ipython

Tags: ipython

I run ipython on Ununtu 10.4 and log session by using     %logstart.

I would like to define a path to a log file where the session would be logged. At the moment I have ipython_log.py in my home dorectory

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `%logstart`should be the path to the logfile. For example:

`%logstart ~/mylog.log`

Try `?%logstart` to read about the available options.